# Is the map method parallel?

Tags: javascript

Is the method `[1, 2, 3].map(item=>f(item))` execute `f(1), f(2), f(3)` parallelly? Or execute like "f(1), then f(2), then f(3)"?

Comment: the second. At the moment there's no concurrency in Ecmascript.

Comment: @MarioVernari Not only "at the moment", but since it's inception and likely for the foreseeable future. The single-threaded nature of JavaScript is at the core of how you use the language.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Atomics and shared arrays are already a native part of the language (but of course, that has nothing to do with `map`, and how/whether one could even start a parallel process is left to the embedder of the language)

Answer (score -2):

### Actually it execute `"f(1), then f(2), then f(3)"?`

Because JS is single-threaded. So if the `f` function is an async task (`setTimeout, Ajax call, etc..`), then it can be `scheduled` to `waits` parallelly combined with `promise.all`. Otherwise, it still has to execute synchronously.

---

One more thing to keep in mind is when you use `await` inside `async` function,
It does only **waits** parallel when you use [`promise.all`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
var tick;
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}`);

const f = (number) => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => log(number), 1000);
   });

async function Run(){
  tick = Date.now();
  await Promise.all([f(1), f(2), f(3)]);
}

function Run_2(){
  tick = Date.now();
  [f(1), f(2), f(3)];
}

Run();
Run_2();
```

While you `await` each `f`, it takes 3s in total.

```js
var tick;
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}`);

const f = (number) => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(number), 1000);
   });

async function Run(){
  tick = Date.now();
  let a = await f(1);
  let b = await f(2);
  let c = await f(3);
  
  log([a, b, c]);
}
Run();
```

However, `Promise.all` can only **waits** async tasks in parallel. It can't convert a *synchronous CPU block code* into a separate thread or anything.

Comment: @PONPON Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: `Promise.all` neither causes parallel processing nor does it do any scheduling. And it has nothing to do with the question about `.map()`.

Comment: Really? 2 examples above tell me that `Promise.all` make the async task run parallel, sir.

Comment: Pls, tell me what I'm wrong Thanks sir @Bergi

Comment: It's the async task that runs in parallel not `Promise.all`. If you call blocking functions and pass them to `Promise.all` they will not be automatically converted to run in parallel. (Even so, `setTimeout()` cannot run anything in parallel due to javascript's single-threaded nature - it only **waits** in parallel)

Comment: @Phong Drop the `Promise.all` call, write just `[f(1), f(2), f(3)]`, and the three timeouts will still happen concurrently.

Comment: @slebetman You mean the same as me `However, Promise.all can only schedule async tasks in parallel. It can't convert a synchronous CPU block code into a separate thread or anything.`

Comment: @Bergi I got what you mean. So when should I use `Promise.all` to get its feature?

Comment: @Phong Then I don't think you've stated your understanding clearly in your answer. Your answer seem to imply that `Promise.all` makes the functions run in parallel. It does not. It only **waits** for parallel. You can prove this to yourself by removing `Promise.all` from your code and seeing that it still waits for the `setTimeout` in parallel even without passing it to `Promise.all`

Comment: @slebetman I got you. **run** different with **waits** ^^!

Comment: I've just updated my answer with your advice, pls kindly take a look at then give me your feedback if it's possible. Many thanks, both of you @slebetman & Bergi.